# Passing System attributes of Amazon connect to Amazon lambda (ex: caller's phone number)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I need to pass the caller's phone number to a lambda fuction to generate a customer id for the caller using caller's phone number, date and time. can someone tell me how to configure "Invoke AWS Lambda function" block to pass the caller's phone number, and the any corrections for my code in lambda

```
import boto3
import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  current_phone_number = event['callerPhoneNumber']
  current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
  current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')

  customer_id = current_phone_number + '-' + current_date + '-' + current_time

  return {
    'CustomerID': customer_id
  }
```

I tried this code and the configuration for the Invoke Lambda block as in the screenshot. But it still gives error in this block

Answer (score 3):

You can find an example event that's passed to the Lambda [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html#function-contact-flow).

Passing the phone number in as a parameter is an option, but it also appears to be available at the path: `event['Details']['ContactData']['CustomerEndpoint']['Address']` in the default data in the message.